# How to see the result of the execution of the procedure without updating data tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have stored procedure with `$UPDATE` inside it. I want to see the result of executing this procedure without doing changes in my tables.

I'm thinking about PRINT and RAISERROR, but I didn't find out how to do it properly - Do I need to modify my procedure, or I can specifically execute my procedure.

Some of my procedure code:

```
...
UPDATE Table SET DateChange = @DateCh
```

Procedure executing

```
GO
DECLARE @UF int
EXECUTE @UF = [dbo].[sp_GoProc] 
GO
```

In the output, I expect to see the updated values in the tables or part of the table that was updated.

Comment: I would urge you to read this question and ask yourself if you would have any idea what you are asking from what you posted.

Comment: @SeanLange changed the question

Comment: Nope....clear as mud. No idea what you want as output here. Are you wanting to return the rows that were updated in a number of update statements throughout the procedure? Think about this, do you see what rows were updated with just a simple update statement? No. You would need a before and after select statement for each update statement.

Comment: Do you want this for temporary testing purposes or is this going to be a permanent feature?

Comment: @SeanLange If I have just an UPDATE query, can I somehow see what will be after the update? Like SELECT PRINT UPDATE ... . In the output will be the result of this update , but datable will not be changed.

Comment: @Saharsh just for the testing

Comment: You use two select statements. One before you update and a second one after.

Comment: If you're not in a production system -- `BEGIN TRANSACTION; EXEC proc;`, `SELECT` to your heart's content for comparison purposes, `ROLLBACK`. If you are on a production system, this is inadvisable, since keeping a transaction open will severely impact other sessions!

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, that it )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is for testing purposes, try this in your stored proc

```
Begin tran
UPDATE Table SET DateChange = @DateCh
Select * from Table where DateChange = @DateCh
Rollback
```

OR

You can keep your stored proc unmodified and wrap the execution in a transaction block

```
Begin tran

DECLARE @RC int
EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[sp_GoProc] 

Select * from Table

Rollback
```

You will see the output of Table with changes when you execute your stored proc, but they'll be rolled back in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

If changing the procedure is acceptable, you can modify any UPDATE into a SELECT to see what would be updated.   For example, change this:

```
UPDATE mt
SET x=1
FROM MyTable mt
JOIN OtherTable ot ON mt.y=ot.y
WHERE SomeCondition='true'
```

to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable mt
JOIN OtherTable ot ON mt.y=ot.y
WHERE SomeCondition='true'
```

That being said, what you're asking for really isn't a good practice.   The Best Practice for testing a procedure that does updates is to make a testing copy of your database, and run the procedure on the test copy.   Then you can look at the actual results of the UPDATE in the test copy, and your real data won't have been affected.

Comment: I have a test database, but after that I will do it on my test base I need to undo the changes somehow, to test it with another variables. It can be done, and I will do that way, thanks

Comment: To "reset" your test database for another run, simple over-write the test tables with the real tables.